# Regarding the Proof of Hartshorne III.7.11

Tags: algebraic-geometry, duality-theorems

[image]

I got two questions regarding the proof:

1. Why we can just assume $A_\mathfrak{m}$ as $A$ if we pick a sufficiently small neighborhood of $x$? (the 7-th line)
2. Why's the last isomorphism true?

Thank you very much in advance for answering my question.

Comment: 1. There is no assumption that $A_\mathfrak{m}=A$. What do you mean? 2. Do you know the definition of the Koszul complex? If you do, you should be able to plug in and calculate this in a straightforwards manner. If not, you probably should look up what the last few terms of the Koszul complex are.

Comment: 1. But the why can we assume the Koszul complex to be the free resolution of the quotient ring?

2. I understand what Koszul complex is. But what involved in the proof was the right derived functor of \mathscr{Hom}. I am new to the subject and I hope to have a more explicit picture.

Comment: This is a consequence of generic freeness. See for instance [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2784127/freeness-of-stalk-implies-locally-free). Stalk-locally at $\mathfrak{m}$, the Koszul complex is free, so then there's some neighborhood $D(f)$ where the Koszul complex is free. Use $D(f)\subset U$ instead of $U$ and you're set.